# what can we do with instagram's access token?

Tags: node.js, api, instagram

I started working with instagram APIs using `node.js` and walked through the official instagram API docs [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer) but it does not explain clearly.

Here I have 2 questions:

1. what is the difference between `Client ID` and `Client Secret`?
2. what is `access_token` ? and what is it used for ? and
   when we should request for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client ID is is basically a unique id assigned to your application by an Oauth provider. It considered public information, and is used to build login URLs, or included in Javascript source code on a page.

An app requesting an access token has to know the client secret in order to gain the token. This prevents malicious apps from ever obtaining a valid access token. The client secret id doesn't state anything about authenticating a user, but it's instead for authorising an app to request access tokens.
The client secret must be kept confidential. If a deployed app cannot keep the secret confidential, such as single-page Javascript apps or native apps, then the secret is not used.

When you login with an Oauth provider, the server responds with an access token and expiration time in ms if the login is successful.

```
{
  "access_token":"RsT5OjbzRn430zqMLgV3Ia",
  "expires_in":3600
}
```

Every time client requests a resource from the server, the server validates the access code. The access-token is used to verify every request from the client. You will request for an access_token whenever you login through an Oauth provider.
You can refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14009/whats-the-benefit-of-the-client-secret-in-oauth2) and [this](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, can we relate access token to stuff like, commenting, liking, and posting on behalf of the user ? I mean in order to do these stuff we should have access token available ?

Comment: Yes, every time you make an API request, the server validates the token. Its purpose is to inform the API/server that the bearer of this token has been authorised to access the API and perform specific actions. Every like, comment and post is a new request. So, you need too have a valid access token issued by the server

Comment: I think i got it